# My android app stops responding after the Splash Screen

Tags: java, android, xml, runtime-error, manifest

I'm programming a new app which contains a splash screen. 
I've finished it and it was all good. After I've opened android studio again to work on the navigation bar I've tried to run the app to see the result but the application stopped and crashed after the display of the splash screen.

this is Main class

```
package com.example.computer.bsinfoshop;




public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    }


}
```

and this is the class od splash screen

```
package com.example.computer.bsinfoshop;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Screen extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv;
    ImageView img;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Satisfy-Regular.ttf");
        tv.setTypeface(font);

        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.rsz_2rsz_img);



        Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try
                {
                    sleep(3700);

                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Screen.this , Main.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        };
        timerThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

and here where i think is the problem

the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.computer.bsinfoshop">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity
            android:name=".Screen"
            android:theme="@style/App">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Information"
            android:label="Information"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.computer.bsinfoshop.Main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I just want to know what is the problem in my code and how can I fix it.  thank you ^^

Comment: *"...but the application stop and crash after the display of the splash screen"* When this happens and you want help, you need to post your stacktrace so we can see the error

Answer (score 0):

Change Thread to something like this:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(Screen.this, Main.class));
        }
    }, 1500);
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely considered high quality. You should consider adding *what* is different about your code and *why* it should solve the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think this is not the correct way of creating a Splash Screen. That way you force the user to wait for 3 seconds which causes a bad user-experience.

Have a look at that tutorial and your users will thank you! https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It should possibly be a comment.

Comment: sorry.. I do not have enough reputation for writing a comment to the question.. that's the problem otherwise I would have done so..